# I got this error "Support user does not have permission on this operation" when I want to give GrantAccess to a record in CRM SDK 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I got this exception:
"Support user does not have permission on this operation"
when I try to give access to a record for a user. this is my code:

```
public void GrantAccess(Guid targetId, Guid principleId)
    {

        using (var service = new OrganizationService(_con))
        {
            var request = new GrantAccessRequest()
            {
                Target = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, targetId),
                PrincipalAccess = new PrincipalAccess()
                {
                    AccessMask = AccessRights.ReadAccess,
                    Principal = new EntityReference(principleId.ToString())
                }
            };
            service.Execute(request);
        }
    }
```

and my Constr is like:

```
private static readonly string ConStr = "Url=http://crm.[ourdomain].com:90/Test; Domain=[ourdomain]; Username=[user]; Password=[password];";
```

I cand read the data, for example I get this method:
RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessResponse
even more I "RevokeAccess" by RevokeAccessRequest, but I couldn't Grant access or modify it.

**Edit1**
Full Stack Error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/ExecuteOrganizationServiceFaultFault
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Support user does not have permission on this operation
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.<>c__DisplayClass19.<Execute>b__18(IOrganizationService s)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.InnerOrganizationService.UsingService[TResult](Func`2 action)
       at Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
       at CRMConsole.Queries.GrantAccess(Guid targetId, Guid principleId) in D:\Projects\CRM\CRMPrivileges\CRMConsole\Queries.cs:line 142
       at CRMConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projects\CRM\CRMPrivileges\CRMConsole\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I checked the user access to the Account entity, and he has the read access to it with User depth. Beside that I can share this entity in crm web page UI with current user that is in connection credential.

Comment: Can you check the exact wording of the error message? Perhaps post the full error message with the stack trace. Also, does the user referred to by `principleId` have Read-Owner permission on the entity type being shared.

Comment: I wrote more detail in Edit1

Comment: What permissions does the user who you are using to connect to CRM, i.e., the user name in the connection string, have in CRM?

Comment: yes. the user, for example, is A, A is in Administration role and I can share this record with user B (principle) in CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so ridiculous but the problem was in this line of code:

```
Principal = new EntityReference(principleId.ToString())
```

we must declare entity name just like this:

```
Principal = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName,principleId)
```